# How to check if a file has been downloaded successfully with selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, download, webdriver

How to check if a file has been downloaded successfully with selenium webdriver ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: See https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/download-file-using-selenium-and-verifying/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method work fine for me

```
public boolean validateFileDownloaded(String downloadPath, String fileName) {
    for (int k = 0; k< 60; k++) {
        File dir = new File(downloadPath);
        File[] dirContents = dir.listFiles();
        if(dirContents == null){
            continue;
        }
        for (File dirContent : dirContents) {
            if (dirContent.getName().contains(fileName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        wait(500);
    }
    return false;
}
```